# SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: node.js, cassandra, syntax-error

I am using Cassandra + Node.js to create an app, but I am receiving an error for this code:

```
C:\Users\userx\node-cassandra\app.js:44
app.post('/',new);
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at Module._compile (module.js:545:28)
```

This is my code

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var helenus = require('helenus');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var pool = new helenus.ConnectionPool({
    hosts      : ['localhost:9160'],
    keyspace   : 'webinar',
    cqlVersion : '3.0.0',
    //user       : 'test',
    //password   : 'test1233',
    //timeout    : 3000
    //cqlVersion : '3.0.0' // specify this if you're using Cassandra 1.1 and       want to use CQL 3 
  });

  pool.connect(function(err){
if(err){
    throw(err);
}


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('cassandra',pool);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/', new);
app.delete('/', delete);;

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app; 
});
```

index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next){
req.app.get('cassandra').cql('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10',function(err, users){
if(err){
  return next(err);
}

res.render('index', { title: 'Users', users: users });
});
};

exports.new = function(req, res, next){
var insert = 'UPDATE users SET first_name=?, last_name=? WHERE email=?',
  params = [req.body.first_name, req.body.last_name, req.body.email];

req.app.get('cassandra').cql(insert,  params, function(err, users){
if(err){
  return next(err);
}

res.redirect('/');
});
};

exports.delete = function(req, res, next){
var remove = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE email=?',
  params = [req.body.email];

req.app.get('cassandra').cql(remove,  params, function(err, users){
if(err){
  return next(err);
}

res.redirect('/');
});
};
```

Error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

i just tried to change the app.post('/',routes.new);

but it showed inheritance mustnot be done

Please tell me where is my mistake

Comment: Maybe if you formatted your code correctly, it would be easier to find.

Comment: what is new here? first it's a keyword so i dont think you can use it, but i dont even see an attempt

Comment: new is the route @aw04

Comment: is routes what's being imported as index? should be index.new in that case

Answer (score 3):

`new` is a [reserved word](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords) in ECMAScript.  I don't think you will be able to use it as a member name as it is being interpreted as creating a new object.

Comment: @StackUser ) is the next character and it's telling you it's not expected, because it expects a new object. think about how the compiler reads it

Comment: Rename the function `new` to something else like `newRoute` for example.